# Is it possible to access UIBarButtonItem using tag?

Tags: iphone

I hope to access UIBarButtonItem on an UIToolbar using tag.
The codes show below

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem=(UIBarButtonItem*)myUIToolBar.items[i];
```

but myBarButtonItem returns no object(0x0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation from Apple:

> The items displayed on the toolbar.
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray
>   *items Discussion The items, instances of UIBarButtonItem, that are visible
>   on the toolbar in the order they
>   appear in this array. Any changes to
>   this property are not animated. Use
>   the setItems:animated: method to
>   animate changes.
>
> The default value is nil

Did you set the items array, can you print out the value of `NSLog(@"%@", myToolBar.items);` to see if it is nil and to see how many UIBarButtonItem inside